# How to run Windows from GRUB

Tags: linux, windows, boot, partitioning, grub

Duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935181/run-windows-from-grub

I have following drive:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD5000LPVX-2 (scsi)
Drive /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logic/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition table: gpt
Drive flags:

Number Start   End    Size    File system       Name                          Flags
 1     1049kB  500MB  499MB   fat32                                           boot, esp
 2     500MB   103GB  102GB   ext4
 3     103GB   111GB  8193MB  linux-swap(v1)
 4     111GB   346GB  235GB                     Basic data partition          msftdata
 5     346GB   346GB  16,8MB                    Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 6     346GB   500GB  154GB   ntfs              Basic data partition          msftdata
```

I don't have access to Windows from GRUB and need to open BIOS settings to  change default boot device, that's very inconvenient. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @AndrewMorton ok, done.

Answer (score 1):

In /boot/grub/grub.cfg is the configuration where grub finds which systems can be booted.
For each system to be booted there is a menu entry which looks like this:

```
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sdc1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-AE200FF6200FC475' {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='hd2,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos1  AE200FF6200FC475
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root AE200FF6200FC475
fi
parttool ${root} hidden-
chainloader +1
```

}

"AE200FF6200FC475" is the UUID of the device where windows can be found. You find this UUID with the linux "blkid" command.